# Replace a substring in Lua with a pattern

Tags: lua, string-substitution

I have a string like this

```
     str = '["username"] = "user";
     ["deepscan"] = "true";
     ["token"] = true;
     ["password"] = "krghfkghkfghf";
     ["uploadMethod"] = "JSON";
     ["serviceIsRunning"] = {};
     ["host"] = "sample.com";
     ["instance_ID"] = 405454058;'
```

I would like the pattern match  `["password"] =` and have it replace only the string in between the `";' that would be '"krghfkghkfghf"` in this instance.

Comment: `str = str:gsub('(%["password"%]%s*=%s*").-"','%1'..new_pwd:gsub('%%','%%%%')..'"')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - why do you always post answers as comments :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local function replacePass(configstr, newpass)
    return configstr:gsub("(%[\"password\"%]%s*=%s*)%b\"\"", "%1\"" .. newpass .. "\"")
end
```

That won't work if your password contains a double quote inside.

Answer (score -1):

i have same question as well, 
how about the following password replace ?

```
"password" : "krghfkghkfghf"
```