# lua sub string replace 2 pattern

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

due to using nginx lua (kong gateway) 
would like to replace 
from

```
{"body":"\r\n  \"username\": \"sampleUser\",\r\n  \"password\": \"samplePassword\",\r\n"}
```

to

```
{"body":"\r\n  \"username\": \"sampleUser\",\r\n  \"password\": \"***REDACTED***\",\r\n"}
```

from

```
username=sampleUser&password=samplePassword
```

to

```
username=sampleUser&password=***REDACTED***
```

from

```
"password" : "krghfkghkfghf"
```

to

```
"password" : "***REDACTED***"
```

i did try on sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638937/712063

```
local function replacePass(configstr, newpass)
return configstr:gsub("(%[\"password\"%]%s*=%s*)%b\"\"", "%1\"" .. newpass .. "\"")
end
```

it does not work, any recommended reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
local t = {
    [[{"body":"\r\n  \"username\": \"sampleUser\",\r\n  \"password\": \"samplePassword\",\r\n"} ]],
    [[username=sampleUser&password=samplePassword]],
    [["password" : "krghfkghkfghf"]]
}

local newpass ="***REDACTED***"
for k,example in pairs(t) do
  res = example:gsub('(password[\\" :]+)(.-)([\\"]+)',"%1"..newpass.."%3") 
  res = res:gsub("(password=).+","%1"..newpass)
  print(res)
end
```

out:

```
{"body":"\r\n  \"username\": \"sampleUser\",\r\n  \"password\": \"***REDACTED***\",\r\n"} 
username=sampleUser&password=***REDACTED***
"password" : "***REDACTED***"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several things wrong with that at first sight.

## 1. You only check for `=`

In your test data you seem to have cases with *key = value* as well as *key : value* but your pattern only checks for `=`; replace that with `[=:]` for a simple fix.

## 2. You can't balance quotation marks

I don't know how you expect this to work, but `[[%b""]]` just finds the shortest possible string between two `"` characters, just as `[[".-"]]` would. If that's your intention, then there's nothing wrong with writing it using `%b` though.

## 3. Just don't

As I don't know the context, I can't say if this really is a bad idea or not, but it does seem like a very brittle solution. If this is an option, I would recommend considering the alternative and going with something more robust.

As for what a better alternative could look like, I can't say without knowledge of your requirements. Maybe normalizing the data into a Lua table and replacing the `password` key in a uniform way? This would make sure that the data is either sanitized, or errors during parsing.

---

Beyond that, it would help if you told us *how* it doesn't work. It's easy to miss bugs when reading someone elses code, but knowing how the code misbehaves can help a lot with actually spotting the problem.

---

EDIT:

## 4. You didn't even remove the brackets

You didn't even remove the `[]` from that other stack overflow answer. Obviously that doesn't work without any modifications.

Comment: hi thanks for response, i just thought put back original work to here, in stead of modify it,
my mistake was 1st one below is my code and it work !

`local function replacePass(configstr)
 local NEWPASS = "***REDACTED***"
    print("replacePass " .. configstr:gsub("(\"password\"%s*[=:]%s*)%b\"\"", "%1\"" .. '***REDACTED***' .. "\""))
end`